# Restar horas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblactividad](
    [CodigoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocRefe] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [NomActivi] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CodTarea] [int] NULL,
    [CodTipo] [int] NULL,
    [CodPrio] [int] NULL,
    [CodEstad] [int] NULL,
    [CodResp] [int] NULL,
    [FCreacion] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FInicio] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FFin] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HInicio] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [HFin] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [CodComplet] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notas] [varchar](1000) NULL,)
```

Necesito restar los campos Hfin - HInicio y que el resultado se guarde en Tiempo, 
y esto pase cada vez que se inserte un registro

ejemplo de lo que he intentado pero no me funcionaaa no se como mas hacerlo gracias

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[RestarHoras] 
ON  [dbo].tblactividad FOR INSERT 
AS

insert into tblactividad tiempo(
Datediff(hour, hfin,hinicio)
)
```

Comment: No te sirve mejor simplemente una columna calculada?

Comment: Pero sirve calcular operaciones, para guardar datos en hora también y guardar el resultado en otro campo ¿?

Comment: Veo que tienes campos separados para fecha y hora de inicio y de fin. ¿Los intervalos pueden ser mayores a 24 horas? Si no lo son, creo que no hace falta almacenar dos fechas, con una es suficiente. También porque para períodos de más de 24 horas, el tipo `time` no es el más adecuado para el campo `Tiempo` .

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la columna tiempo está definida como `time` cuando debería estar definida como `int` que es el resultado que arroja `DATEDIFF`.

Si la columna tiempo siempre será la diferencia entre hinicio y hfin, puedes dejarlo como una columna calculada.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblactividad](
    [CodigoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocRefe] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [NomActivi] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CodTarea] [int] NULL,
    [CodTipo] [int] NULL,
    [CodPrio] [int] NULL,
    [CodEstad] [int] NULL,
    [CodResp] [int] NULL,
    [FCreacion] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FInicio] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FFin] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HInicio] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [HFin] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] AS DATEDIFF( HH, HInicio, HFin),
    [CodComplet] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notas] [varchar](1000) NULL,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien, y sin entrar en la utilidad de la misma o si es buena o mala práctica, lo que buscas es poder actualizar el campo `Tiempo` cuando se inserte un registro en ese tabla con la diferencia entre horas de los campos `HInicio` y `HFin`.

Prueba con esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.RestarHoras ON dbo.tblactividad
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Actualiza con la diferencia de horas entre HInicio y HFin
    UPDATE [dbo].[tblactividad]
    SET [Tiempo] = (
            SELECT CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(SS, HInicio, HFin) * 1000, 0), 114)
            FROM inserted i
            )
    WHERE CodigoID = (
            SELECT i.CodigoID
            FROM inserted i
            )
END
GO
```

Ya nos contarás.