# Columna calculada

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta tabla con el campo tiempo calculado restando los campos HFin - HIncio
pero me sale el siguiente Msg

el resultado que debería aparecer en el campo Tiempo es la resta de dos horas es decir si en HInicio esta la hora  10:30 y en Hfin las 11:00 deberia poner en el campo Tiempo 30 Min que es la diferencia entre las dos horas

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblactividad](
    [CodigoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [DocRefe] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [NomActivi] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CodTarea] [int] NULL,
    [CodTipo] [int] NULL,
    [CodPrio] [int] NULL,
    [CodEstad] [int] NULL,
    [CodResp] [int] NULL,
    [FCreacion] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FInicio] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FFin] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HInicio] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [HFin] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] AS (HFin-HInicio) PERSISTED,  
    [CodComplet] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notas] [varchar](1000) NULL,)
```

**Msg**
**Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator.**

me pueden ayudar he hecho de  todo para hacer esto no me a dado de ninguna forma

Comment: ¿Es aceptable un número de coma flotante que te indique el número de horas transcurridas? \En ese caso, 30 minutos serían 0.5 horas y 1:45 sería 1.75 horas. ¿Qué precisión debe tener ese tiempo? ¿En algún caso vas a almacenar más de 24 horas?

Comment: debería ser lo mas atendible para el usuario  la precisión del tiempo debe ser exacta si la diferencia es de  30Min debería aparecer  30  si es de 1:45 debería ser igual a  1:45 y si va almacenar mas de  24  horas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las columnas `time` no pueden restarse mediante el operador `-`, para estos casos debes hacer por ejemplo: `[Tiempo] AS datediff(ss,HFin,HInicio) PERSISTED` para obtener la diferencia en segundos. Sin embargo, por lo que mencionas, necesitas resolver una columna que muestre un valor legible con la diferencia en horas, minutos y segundos. Por lo que entonces hay dos problemas a resolver, (a) como generar esta representación y (b) como agregar está a la estructura de la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblactividad](
    [HInicio] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [HFin] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] AS 
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, HInicio, HFin) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, HInicio, HFin) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, HInicio, HFin) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) PERSISTED
)
```

Con `datediff` calculamos diferencias en segundos, luego con un poco de aritmética calculamos cada parte de la diferencia. Finalmente:

```
INSERT INTO tblactividad (HInicio, HFin) 
  VALUES ('00:12:05', '21:31:14'), 
         ('15:27:34', '16:55:02');

select *
    from tblactividad;

|          HInicio |             HFin |   Tiempo |
|------------------|------------------|----------|
| 00:12:05.0000000 | 21:31:14.0000000 | 21:19:09 |
| 15:27:34.0000000 | 16:55:02.0000000 | 01:27:28 |
```

Puedes volver a la idea de un trigger si te parece viendo esto: [Trigger para restar fechas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83894/trigger-para-restar-fechas)

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ya veo que has cambiado de planteamiento con esta tabla respecto a la [otra entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272227/restar-horas-en-sql-server/272247) que habías puesto.

Prueba con esto

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblactividad](
    [CodigoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [DocRefe] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [NomActivi] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CodTarea] [int] NULL,
    [CodTipo] [int] NULL,
    [CodPrio] [int] NULL,
    [CodEstad] [int] NULL,
    [CodResp] [int] NULL,
    [FCreacion] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FInicio] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FFin] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HInicio] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [HFin] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Tiempo] AS (CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(SS, HInicio, HFin) * 1000, 0), 114)) PERSISTED,  
    [CodComplet] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notas] [varchar](1000) NULL,)
```